# Как сделать рамки вокруг блока разного цвета?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, border

Как сделать рамки блока как на рисунке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: border-top: 1px solid blue; border-right: 1px solid red; border-left: 1px solid red;  border-bottom: 1px solid red;

Comment: Здравствуйте. Для изучения вам: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border и https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
p {
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Задача организации, в особенности же начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции в значительной степени обуславливает создание новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также консультация с широким активом влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации соответствующий условий активизации.Задача организации, в особенности же начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции в значительной степени обуславливает создание новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также консультация с широким активом влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации соответствующий условий активизации.Задача организации, в особенности же начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции в значительной степени обуславливает создание новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также консультация с широким активом влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации соответствующий условий активизации.</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.block {
   border: 5px solid red;
   border-top: 5px solid green;
}
.block2 {
   border: 5px solid red;
   border-top-color: green;
}
div {
   margin-bottom:10px;
   width:150px;
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
div {
  border: 1em solid red;
  border-top-color: blue;

  margin: 1em;
  height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
div
  {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-top: 2px blue solid;
    border-bottom: 2px red groove;
    border-left: 5px green dotted;
    border-right: 5px aqua groove;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Для каждой стороны можно разные: цвет, стиль, толщину, радиус

Answer (score 4):

На **box-shadow**, если кому надо..

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: gray;
  box-shadow: 
    0 2px 0 0 red,    /* bottom */
    0 -2px 0 0 blue,  /* top */
    2px 0 0 0 red,    /* right */
    -2px 0 0 0 red;   /* left */
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```